# Cannot choose files from storage from downloads

Tags: android, storage, file-storage

I need help. I cannot choose files from downloads, but from another folder from storage I can. In the screen in downloads, I can see files, but there are not available for choosing. What is my mistake?
here is my code:

```
String[] mimeTypes = new String[]{PDF_MIME_TYPE, MP4_MIME_TYPE, MKV_MIME_TYPE,
            AVI_MIME_TYPE, MOV_MIME_TYPE, DOCX_MIME_TYPE, XLSX_MIME_TYPE, PPTX_MIME_TYPE};
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
        startActivityForResult(intent, "12");
```

[image]

Comment: Do away with those mime types. And that extra local only.

Comment: You posted a picture on which we cannot see if the mimetypes (read: extensions) are the one you want. And you cannot see that either ;-)

Comment: @blackapps, hi, thanks for your answer. I try load *xlsx and *pptx files.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @blackapps, I removed mime types and added additional permissions:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_FROM_DIALOG);
}
```